# Set input group min and max value dynamically

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to update or validate the min and max value of my dynamic input-group inputs with plus and minus button.

Here's what I've done so far:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="center">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-number" data-type="minus" data-field="numbergroup'+thisgroupid+'id'+buttonid+'max&'+row.max+'"">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
      </button>
    </span>
    <input type="text" name="numbergroup'+thisgroupid+'id'+buttonid+'max&'+row.max+'"" value="0" class="form-control input-number" min="'+row2.min+'"  max="'+row2.max+'">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="numbergroup'+thisgroupid+'id'+buttonid+'max&'+row.max+'"">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

***JS***

```
 $('.btn-number').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
fieldName = $(this).attr('data-field');
console.log(fieldName)
 var grpmax = fieldName.split('&')[1];
 console.log(grpmax)
type      = $(this).attr('data-type');
 console.log(type)
var input = $("input[name='"+fieldName+"']");
var currentVal = parseInt(input.val());
if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
    if(type == 'minus') {
        if(currentVal > input.attr('min')) {
            input.val(currentVal - 1).change();
        } 
        if(parseInt(input.val()) == input.attr('min')) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        }

    } else if(type == 'plus') {

        if(currentVal < input.attr('max')) {
            input.val(currentVal + 1).change();
        }
        if(parseInt(input.val()) == input.attr('max')) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        }
    }
} else {
    input.val(0);
}
});
$('.input-number').focusin(function(){
   $(this).data('oldValue', $(this).val());
});
$('.input-number').change(function() {

minValue =  parseInt($(this).attr('min'));
maxValue =  parseInt($(this).attr('max'));
valueCurrent = parseInt($(this).val());

name = $(this).attr('name');
if(valueCurrent >= minValue) {
    $(".btn-number[data-type='minus'][data-field='"+name+"']").removeAttr('disabled')
} else {
    alert('Sorry, the minimum value was reached');
    $(this).val($(this).data('oldValue'));
}
if(valueCurrent <= maxValue) {
    $(".btn-number[data-type='plus'][data-field='"+name+"']").removeAttr('disabled')
} else {
    alert('Sorry, the maximum value was reached');
    $(this).val($(this).data('oldValue'));
 }


 });
 $(".input-number").keydown(function (e) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 190]) !== -1 ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
         // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

I'm setting the `min` and `max` values for each input field, but I'm not setting the `min` and `max` values for each input groups that will be created. I need to set the group max value or add validation to check if the group's total value is less than or equal to *grpmax*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
function add(groupId,val) {
  let inp = document.querySelector(`[name=numbergroup_${groupId}]`);
  inp.value= +inp.value + val;
  if(inp.value<+inp.min) inp.value=inp.min;
  if(inp.value>+inp.max) inp.value=inp.max;
}
```

```html
Min:-2, Max:5
<div class="center">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" onclick="add(123,-1)" >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">-</span>
      </button>
    </span>
    <input type="text" name="numbergroup_123" value="0"  min="-2"  max="5">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" onclick="add(123,1)" >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">+</span>
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```